# Rails 4 how to check if nested attributes _destroy flag is set from within model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, accepts-nested-attributes

I have model (container) that accepts nested attributes (including `allow_destroy`) for  a `has_one` relationship to another model (reuse_request). There is a `before_validation` callback in the container model that I don't want to run if the the reuse_request is about to be destroyed in the same update.

Is there a way to check if the `_destroy` attribute has been passed from within the container model `before_validation` callback?

```
#container.rb
before_validation :set_code
has_one :reuse_request_as_previous, class_name: 'ReuseRequest', foreign_key: 'previous_container_id', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :previous_container
accepts_nested_attributes_for :reuse_request_as_new, :allow_destroy => true

def set_code
  if reuse_request_as_new && reuse_request_as_new.previous_container
    self.code = reuse_request_as_new.previous_container.code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `.marked_for_destruction?`?

```
def set_code
  return if reuse_request_as_new.marked_for_destruction?
  ...
end
```